Tennis Doubles playing scheduling with 9 players
I'm trying to arrange a friendly doubles tennis playing schedule for 9 players. For those who aren't familiar, in a doubles tennis game, 2 players are on the same team and play together against another 2 players.
I have 9 players joining. I would like to arrange a playing schedule such that each player gets to pair up with each other player at least once, and each player also gets to play against each other player against once. The schedule should be arranged as equally as possible to maximize equal playing time.
Since there are an odd number of players, 1 player will need to sit out each time the 8 other players play. For example, if the players are coded A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, then we can have:
Round 1: [A & B vs C & D] and [E & F vs G & H] with I sitting out.
Any help would be appreciated!

Obviously you need 9 (or more) rounds to distribute the turns to sit out equally.
Organizers of bridge tournaments have a need for arrangements like these. Their requirements contain all of yours (and a few extras). The following is from http://sicherman.net/bridge/index.html. You want to scroll down to individual movements (more often than not in a bridge tournament a pair sticks together throughou, like in Wimbledon, but there are events for individuals also). You can ignore the information about the board numbers given that in a tennis tournament your probably have no need to assign particular sets of balls to each match or some such :-)
Round 1: 4+7 vs. 2+3,  5+9 vs. 8+6
Round 2: 5+8 vs. 3+1,  6+7 vs. 9+4
Round 3: 6+9 vs. 1+2,  4+8 vs. 7+5
Round 4: 7+1 vs. 5+6,  8+3 vs. 2+9
Round 5: 8+2 vs. 6+4,  9+1 vs. 3+7
Round 6: 9+3 vs. 4+5,  7+2 vs. 1+8
Round 7: 1+4 vs. 8+9,  2+6 vs. 5+3
Round 8: 2+5 vs. 9+7,  3+4 vs. 6+1
Round 9: 3+6 vs. 7+8,  1+5 vs. 4+2
You see that player number n sits out on round number n. Each player partners with every other player once, and has every other player as an opponent twice. If you assign the first match of each round to court #1 and the second match to court #2, then each player will also play on both courts exactly four times. Also, each player appears as the first player of either pair on each court exactly once. This may help, if you need to assign captain's privileges/duties, first-to-serve turns or some such.
My guess is that this may be from a family of algebraic constructions. Anyway, the theme is well-studied.
